# adb Install Burp CA as a system-level trusted CA

Tags: android, adb

**Install Burp CA as a system-level trusted CA**

> i have in my phone android 11  and i have root my phone using Magisk

in Magisk i allow ADB and shell and APPS

> but on i try to connect my phone using adb in my pc  as root i get this error

```
C:\Users\user>adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds

C:\Users\user>adb remount
/system/bin/sh: remount: inaccessible or not found

but i can connect shell ad su but i have read only error

C:\Users\user>adb shell
a21s:/ $ su
1|a21s:/ # mv /sdcard/9a5ba575.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/
mv: /system/etc/security/cacerts//9a5ba575.0: Read-only file system
```

Comment: There are special Magisk modules available which copy the user CA certs into system CA certs at boot. As you can no longer modify the system partition you can not manually do this in a persistent way.

Comment: I activated this, but I faced a problem that the BURP certificate could not be installed as a VPN certificate. The certificate was placed on the system, but the problem is that it only works on Google Chrome and does not work for other applications